# Android - How to place ImageView in relation to the parents center?

Tags: android, imageview, center

The question is pretty straightforward. I want to place an ImageView so
that it is aligned with the parents left side and the parents horizontal center.
Is this possible without adding other layouts etc. ?

EDIT:
Here is an image of what i want. Not that the ImageView should align with the parents horizontal center. The height of the ImageView is not important.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I know this what you don't want, but it is the way to get what you want:

```
 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent" />
     <View
         android:id="@+id/anchor"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/anchor" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Pre-Edit:

I would specifically put it in a RelativeLayout with these attributes:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ... whatever else you need />
```

I'm assuming here you want it to be centered vertically as it would be impossible to be aligned left and horizontally centered.

Answer (score 2):

it pretty much depends what type of parent layout have you choose.

can you post an image of how you would like to look like?

to center your image you can use

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

or

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

also if you have an RelativeLayout as a parent, you can align your ImageView related to other nearby elements:

```
android:layout_above="@id/neighbour"
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/who_to_align_left_with"
```

and so on, you have attributes for all the directions.

This might be useful too

[Android Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

EDIT:

Now I think I understand what you wanted to;
to center the parent use this attribute:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

and for the ImageView use this attribute

```
android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
```

Comment: I have edited my question to include an image of what I want :)