# Centering an Image within the ImageView?

Tags: java, image, javafx-2

My question is pretty simple. In the ImageView, the Image is on the top left. I want it to be in the center. Is there any way to do this?

NB: My question is not asking how to center the ImageView among it's parent, like [this Android question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783862/android-how-to-place-imageview-in-relation-to-the-parents-center), but centering the actual image *within* the ImageView.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `Group` layout ?

Comment: No, I am not. Should I be?

Comment: No, I just viewed an `ImageView` within an `StackPane` and it was centred.

Comment: It's not about the ImageView, it's about what's *inside* it. The actual image. Centering it inside of the ImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "the image is located on the topleft". A JavaFX [ImageView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) has a property called [viewport](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#viewportProperty) which defines what part of the image is visible. So you can't relocate the image itself - you have to redefine the view on it.